# Is there a way to manipulate terminal zoom and size with code using the standard library and essential POSIX libraries?

Tags: c

I am searching for a way to change the:

- terminal zoom (primary)
- terminal dimensions (secondary)

using only the standard C library and established essential libraries such as `<unistd.h>` and `<termios.h>`, etc. Using ncurses is not allowed.

Comment: Any program adjusting my terminal rather than conforming to my terminal is going straight out the window.

Comment: You could try sending the same escape codes as the `resizeterm` function from ncurses. These would depend on the type of terminal, if supported at all.

Comment: Also check [Xterm Control Sequences](https://www.xfree86.org/current/ctlseqs.html). There are sequences for changing fonts etc. Whether or not they are supported by your terminal (if not using xterm) is another matter!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Standard C library (as in ISO 9899:2018 or similar) doesn't know what a terminal is, much less how to change one.  The answer to that is "NO" — the Standard C library has no such functions.

Originally (once upon a long time ago), terminals were hardware screens attached to a computer via an RS232 cable — Wyse 60 and DEC VT100 are two examples.  Such terminals could not be resized — though you could sometimes change the display so that instead of 24x80 you got some larger number of columns to use.

If you're referring to a graphical terminal window on a modern Unix-based system, there probably are ways to change the size, but they involve using the insides of X11 — definitely not particularly easy, and definitely not provided by POSIX via `<unistd.h>` or `<termios.h>`; I don't think standard `<curses.h>` or `<ncurses.h>` would help either.  And the mention of X11 immediately implies that it won't be portable to Windows, and what might work on Windows won't work on Unix — the API for Windows will be different.

Comment: OP mentions `unistd.h` and `termios.h`, so I guess Windows is not relevant. Definitely X11 is the answer (I don't know how to use it), but probably not good for OP.